# Remove share block against user

Tags: powershell, network-share

I had a user recently attempt to upload a .txt which trigger sophos and now has been blocked from every share on the entire network, which is problematic as this is over 1,000 shares and doing manually isn't realistic.

[image]

Part of my issue is that I don't know how to exactly ask this question but how exactly do I remove these blocks via PowerShell?

Within here when going to properties I see this list here

[image]

How can I go around removing these blocks from all shares?

Comment: You would use the smbshare powershell module.  `import-module smbshare`.  Once installed you can `get-command -Module smbshare to see all of the cmdlets.  Create a txt file with all the computers with share that require remediation and loop through the list getting the shares with `get-smbshare' to act upon all of the shares and remove the deny entry.  Good luck!